# Ember / browser refresh button / reload entire site / resetting everything. How to override that behavior?

Tags: ember.js

Apparently when you hit the refresh button, the browser reloads the entire site (with all the scripts), resetting everything, including the "loggedInUser" I put in the application controller.... Is it the browser thing? Or ember thing?

How to stop any of them / both to just stop doing that...? Or should I take the non-trivial route of storing stuffs in browser local storage, etc? Really?

Thanks,
Raka

Comment: Your application should take care of such refreshes, take a look on http://eviltrout.com/2014/04/10/the-refresh-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too difficult to keep the state of your app on browser refresh. I chose to store an auth token, user id, and user role in cookies. Here is an Auth Manager object that can be used to manage the client side of user authentication.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/javascriptcowboy/73410b6b00c8c374401e) auth_manager.js

I instantiate it when the app loads, and call it's 'authenticate' method on init, and when a user successfully authenticates from the server, like in my login or sign up controllers.

I hope this points you in the right direction.